# Is there any such thing as "too many indexes" when it comes to speed in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

I wanted to improve the performance on my SQLite3 database. I went with the most extreme course of action first (just to see what would happen) and added an index to every column of every table in the database.

The database size more than doubled, and to my surprise, performance dropped drastically. Where I had previously gotten 4000 selects per second I now get ~50 selects per second.

This question is not specifically about my case. My question is; is it possible that *adding indexes* will *decrease* `SELECT` performance in SQLite3? I'm asking because I want to know if my problem is that I added too many indexes, or if I've made a mistake somewhere that is causing the slowdown.

---

To be more specific about *my* case: the database increased from 140 MB to 280 MB and I have an SSD.

Comment: You've answered yourself in the question there - adding too many indexes slowed down your selects, from your own metrics.

Comment: The only columns that you wanna index are the ones that you will be searching on.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: By adding lots of indexes I changed a lot of the SQL. I don't know if I messed up the performance by making a mistake in the SQL, or if the performance decreased because of an over-use of indexes.

Comment: @ElGavilan: I have a table with ~8 columns and I want to be able to search quickly on every column, and every combination of columns. Would the right course of action be to index all the columns?

Comment: Indexes can have multiple columns; to be thorough, you must index *every permutation* of columns. ☺

Comment: @CL: Won't individual indexes help me at all if I'm filtering by several columns?

Comment: In a single query, a database can use at most one index per table.

Comment: @CL: That blew my mind a little. I had no idea. That makes most of my indexes useless! But just to be sure; If I have an index with columns (col1, col2, col3, col4), that index will still be used to filter queries for (col1, col2)? In other words, I don't have to use the *entire* index, do I?

Comment: @Codemonkey: Main reason against lots of indexes is that they slow down INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. As you can imagine - each of those actions need to modify data in table, as well as all indexes referring to it. If you are making inserts/updates and selects, you may see selects as being slower, but in fact those are inserts/updates that are slowing things down. SELECTs themself should speed up with indexes, but not if you do INSERTs, etc in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a mechanisms by which additional indexes could cause a slowdown:

1. Most optimization decisions are designed for the worst case – when you're accessing data that is too large to fit into any cache and has to be loaded from disk.

   If the data itself fits into the caches, but all the various indexes used by your queries are so large that the entire working set becomes too large, you will get more swapping.
2. SELECT queries will ignore any indexes that are not actually used.
   However, INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements must update *all* indexes of the changed table, so every additional index will slow down such changes.

Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to check which indexes are actually used by a query.

Read [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) to understand how indexes can be used.